# css counter-increment in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

This is an ordered list I'd like to recreate in angularjs,
Ignore the fact the steps start at 0, these will be changed to other content later.

[image: proper]

Its source is here and the numbers are generated by css counter-increment

**HTML**

```
    <ul id="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Step 0</li>
        <li>Step 1</li>
        <li>Step 2</li>
        <li>Step 3</li>         
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```css
/*custom font*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat);

/*basic reset*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

html {
 height: 100%;
 /*Image only BG fallback*/
 background: url('gs.png');
 /*background = gradient + image pattern combo*/
 background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(196, 102, 0, 0.2), rgba(155, 89, 182, 0.2)), 
  url('gs.png');
}

body {
 font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
 background-color: transparent !important;
}
/*form styles*/
#msform {
 width: 480px;
 margin: 50px auto;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
#msform fieldset {
 background: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
 padding: 20px 30px;
 
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 10%;
 
 /*stacking fieldsets above each other*/
 position: absolute;
}
/*Hide all except first fieldset*/
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
 display: none;
}
/*inputs*/
#msform input, #msform textarea {
 padding: 15px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: montserrat;
 color: #2C3E50;
 font-size: 13px;
}
/*buttons*/
#msform .action-button {
 width: 100px;
 background: #27AE60;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 border: 0 none;
 border-radius: 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px 5px;
 margin: 10px 5px;
}
#msform .action-button:hover, #msform .action-button:focus {
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px white, 0 0 0 3px #27AE60;
}
/*headings*/
.fs-title {
 font-size: 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #2C3E50;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.fs-subtitle {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: #666;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
/*progressbar*/
#progressbar {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 overflow: hidden;
 /*CSS counters to number the steps*/
 counter-reset: step;
}
#progressbar li {
 list-style-type: none;
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 9px;
 /* width should be 100 divided by the number of steps */
 width: 14.2857%;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}
#progressbar li:before {
 content: counter(step);
 counter-increment: step;
 width: 20px;
 line-height: 20px;
 display: block;
 font-size: 10px;
 color: #333;
 background: white;
 border-radius: 3px;
 margin: 0 auto 5px auto;
}
/*progressbar connectors*/
#progressbar li:after {
 content: '';
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 background: white;
 position: absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: 9px;
 z-index: -1; /*put it behind the numbers*/
}
#progressbar li:first-child:after {
 /*connector not needed before the first step*/
 content: none; 
}
/*marking active/completed steps green*/
/*The number of the step and the connector before it = green*/
#progressbar li.active:before,  #progressbar li.active:after{
 background: #27AE60;
 color: white;
}

.rbContainer{ 
 white-space:nowrap;
 text-align: center;
}
.rbContainerN{ 
 white-space:nowrap;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -50px;
}

.rbContainerL{ 
 white-space:nowrap;
 float: left;
}
.rbContainerR{ 
 white-space:nowrap;
 float: right;
}
.lblY { float:left;  }
.inY { float:left;  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module("swiz", []).controller("bCtrl", function($scope) {
      $scope.fieldsets = [
        "Q 1",
        "Q 2",
        "Q 3",
        "Q 4"
      ];
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app='swiz' ng-controller="bCtrl">
  <ul id="progressbar">

    <div ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets">

      <li class="active" ng-if="$first">{{fieldset}}</li>

      <li ng-if="!$first">{{fieldset}}</li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

***Update**: So yes the `ng-repeat` was on the `ul` tag. but it also needs to be on a `div` inside the `ul` (I'm a bit rusty)

The connections are still not showing up

Comment: could you please create a jsFiddle sample already loaded with Angular and all necessary resources? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place the `ng-repeat` on the `<li>` not the `<ul>`. The styling is messed up because it's creating a new `<ul>` each time.

```
<ul id="progressbar">
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets" >
    {{fieldset}}
  </li> 
</ul>
```

**Update**

You can still put the `ng-repeat` inside of the `<li>`. Just use `ng-class` to change out the class instead of `ng-if`.

```
<ul id="progressbar">
    <li ng-class="{active: $first}" ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets">
      {{fieldset}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s9z4js78/)**

Comment: I've added some working code to reflect your contribution. I need the ng-repeat on a div inside the ul so the li classes can be active or not.

Comment: @user1550052, I've updated my answer to fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As Hunter said, the element you want to repeat is the `<li>`, not the `<ul>`, so you should place `ng-repeat` on the `<li>`.

Also, try using `ng-class` instead of declaring two different `<li>` with the class `.active` and another one without it. The class `.active` will be added only if the condition is met.

```
<ul id="progressbar">

  <li ng-class="{'active': $index == $first }" ng-repeat="fieldset in fieldsets" >
    step {{$index}}
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

And also, use this line for `active` class

```
<li ng-class="$index==0 ? 'active' : ''" ></li>
```

or

```
<li ng-class="$first? 'active' : ''" ></li>
```